# Core Data Widget Basic Function in Main App Delegate?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2

I just started working on implementing a widget feature into my Swift 2.0 iOS application and after much research I found the SwiftWidget github link that uses a CoreDataStore file which contains all of the Core Data functions that are normally included in the App Delegate plus the ability to set it to main queue or private queue which is nice.

My question is however do I really need to set this outside of the App Delegate as my app only uses basic core data features and isn't a large database by any means. I ask only because I created a clone version of my app to experiment with changes and trying to use the file that was in the SwiftWidget modified to include all my app info.

For those interested in the actually code this file uses I have linked it below:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

public class CoreDataStore {


class var sharedInstance : CoreDataStore {
struct Static {
    static let instance : CoreDataStore = CoreDataStore()
    }
    return Static.instance
}
// MARK: - Notifications

func contextDidSavePrivateQueueContext(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let context = self.mainQueueCtxt {
        self.synced(self, closure: { () -> () in
            context.performBlock({() -> Void in
                context.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
            })
        })
    }
}

func contextDidSaveMainQueueContext(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let context = self.privateQueueCtxt {
        self.synced(self, closure: { () -> () in
            context.performBlock({() -> Void in
                context.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
            })
        })
    }
}

func synced(lock: AnyObject, closure: () -> ()) {
    objc_sync_enter(lock)
    closure()
    objc_sync_exit(lock)
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.xxx.Appname" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] 
    }()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Appname", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    let directory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.xxx.Appname")

    let url = directory?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Appname.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()

    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }

    return coordinator

    }()

// MARK: - NSManagedObject Contexts

public class func mainQueueContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    return self.sharedInstance.mainQueueCtxt!
}

public class func privateQueueContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    return self.sharedInstance.privateQueueCtxt!
}

lazy var mainQueueCtxt: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

lazy var privateQueueCtxt: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

public class func saveContext (context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    if let moc = context {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges {
            do {
                try moc.save()
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
}
}

// MARK: - NSManagedObject Extension

 extension NSManagedObject {

public class func createInContext(entityName: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> AnyObject {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context)
    return NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}

public class func findAllInContext(entityName: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    var error: NSError?
    let result: [AnyObject]?
    do {
        result = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        result = nil
    }
    return result
}
}
```

Again to repeat the primary question can I effectively read/write to core data from both my primary application and the today extension, using just the App Delegate functions either inside of the App Delegate or by transferring those functions to a .swift file? If not and This type of file is what is needed am I going to be able to use the same fetch commands and save commands as in the app delegate or do I need to rewrite all of my view controller codes fetching and saving to call the specified function of createincontext or findallincontext? If I am not really fetching online data or exporting online data at the moment should I just use the stack build from the app delegate?

Is MagicRecord a better way of achieving these functions and still allowing future ability to implement abilities to fetch and send online data? I already wrote most of my code to functions related to the app delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppDelegate's job is to handle application launch, exit, and background/foreground transitions. Your Core Data stack's job is to handle your data model. These are separate areas of responsibilities, and belong in separate classes.

Yes, you can jumble all of it into the AppDelegate. And for a toy project, you'll get away with it. But it's sloppy practice. What will you do when you want to pull that data model code out and use it in another project? Or port your project from iOS to tvOS or OS X?

Comment: I am curious as to why after all this time apple hasn't actually switched where the core data stack is created when creating a project initially. It seems to me like the Swift approach to things would be to have the core data stack setup in it's own .swift file so that it is ready to be used without needing to modify much for basic core data usage. Regardless of my opinion for just basic save functions and fetch functions the core data stack in the app delegate should be able to be copied to it's own file and then initialized as a class correct?

Comment: Yes, putting it in its own class is fine, and is what I do in my own projects. There are lots of bad examples in Apple's template code! Don't necessarily look to them as samples of best practices. As for Core Data, take a look at Marcus Zarra's stack, which deals well with multiple parent/child contexts, saving at the right time and quickly, and keeping the boundaries clean. This post is in Objective-C but you can use the same logic in Swift: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/

Comment: After reading your comment I decided to take on the task of converting everything over to it's own file and implemented a save call on suspending the application as well as when it is closed. The one thing I am still learning about but think I have a understanding of now after hours of reading is concurrancy. I am not sure if it is needed for my model but the idea of saving in the background and not having it on the main thread that loads basic user functions is appealing to me. I will read the article though I am not completely proficient in Objective-C I am sure the concept is the same.

Comment: Yes, the APIs are the same. They're just pronounced differently in Swift than in Objective-C. The WWDC videos on Core Data in recent years cover concurrency.